# Where can I source extra long headers from

Tags: arduino, header, sourcing, protoboard, enc28j60

I have recently purchased a sparkfun protoboard that I wish to stack above an ethernet shield. (I have 2 different ethernet shields, an Arduino one and a seeed studio enc28j60 shield.)

The problem I have is that if I use the supplied headers, or even the longer "Arduino Stackable header" then the magjack from the ethernet shield below contacts the protoboard. This happens before adding the components at the front of the board, I suspect that if I solder those in the header won't even make reliable contact.

So, I'd like to source some extra long headers, either male-male or male-female would be fine. I did notice that the Arduino ethernet shield has extra long headers - does anyone know where to source those or any other 1.5cm long headers from?

It would be awesome if the supplier had a reasonable shipping rate to Australia, but I'll take whatever I can get. :) I have searched farnell without luck so far, but the number of products is a bit bewildering so there is a chance I have overlooked the perfect header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a second set of long headers, push them into the ethernet board and then push the protoboad into them.

Comment: Hi JohnC,

That's a good idea. I'll use that if I can't get longer headers.

Answer (score 3):

Digikey has [lots of different sizes](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=1442672). Here's a really really long one: [SAM1067-50-ND](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=SAM1067-50-ND) (not exactly cheap though, $18 for 10pcs, with 50 pins each)

[image: long header]
<sub>(source: [davr.org](http://davr.org/pics/TSW-150-17-T-S.JPG))</sub>

No idea on Digikey's policy of shipping to Australia though, but it's quite reasonable pricing for in the USA.

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to look at their [board stackers](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=1442852) page.  Basically the same thing, but (usually) with two insulating strips with some space between them.  We use some 1" 50-position headers on som relay boards at work, and they are a pain because the ends are always getting bent out of alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://www.littlebirdelectronics.com/products/arduino-stackable-header-8-pin) the sort of thing you had in mind or do you need longer ones still? They appear to have other options too, I searched for Headers on the site these were on the second page.

Comment: Hi Amos, 

I'm looking for even longer than those. The pins on those are 10mm long - however the pins on the ethernet shield are 15 mm long.

Comment: littlebirdceo and mad_z work who are Site Admins here work for Little Bird Electronics in Sidney, which is where I got that link from, maybe they'll be able to find you some.

Comment: Littlebirdceo and mad_z are no longer admins since the SE 2.0 switch.

Comment: I posted this over 12 months ago when they still were, do you need me to delete/edit the comment to bring it up to date. It might take me a while to check every post or comment I've made on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Are these long enough:

In one salvage job I found some "double ended" headers, long pins on both ends. These can be very handy because once plugged in they can be used to let you plug in female connectors ( like those on hard drive cables ( but just one of the two sides ) to the board.  Hard part to find. But wait, you can solder two regular headers back to back.

http://www.opencircuits.com/Solderless_protoboard#More_Tips

Answer (score 1):

[Samtec](http://www.samtec.com) make every kind of header you can imagine, and have a very good sample service

Answer (score 0):

On eBay use search criteria "Arduino 15 mm Headers"...
You'll get some 16 entries, very reasonably priced with free shipping...
They have 10 piece and 100 piece entries for 10 8 and 6 pin headers...
If you're using ICSP, either cut & double, or buy the 2 row 5 piece - 2 x 18 sets, which you will need to slice out 3 pin sets, sacrificing 1 or 2 pins in-between, and be carefull at what height you solder them in, to excatly match the other heights... I also noticed the new ones from Arduino come with printing on the sides... All pins individually identified... GREAT...! Arduino should add some dozen new products... These 15 mm labeled header sets, UNO R3, Due, Tre, Mega, Pi, etc...

Comment: fyi.  Sourcing questions are off-topic on EE.SE.  This old one remained open as long as it did because the standards were more relaxed back when it was originally posted.