# What part is like a male header with long pins on both sides?

Tags: components, identification, breadboard, header

What is the part in the picture below? It's like a male header, but with long pins on both sides. I've got some temperature probes I've built that end in female connectors and I'd like to use something similar to use the probes with a breadboard. I've looked on Digikey under headers and haven't been able to find anything.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532/where-can-i-source-extra-long-headers-from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part is available on Digikey with their part number PCC36SFAN-ND:  
[Sullins Connector Solutions PCC36SFAN](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PCC36SFAN/PCC36SFAN-ND/935992). A [PDF drawing](http://www.sullinscorp.com/catalogs/97_Page78-79_HEADER_.100_2.54mm_MALE_BREAKAWAY.pdf) of the connector is available from Sullins.

It's just a single row male header.  What I've done when the lengths aren't quite right is just order it longer on one end, and then push the plastic bit so it shifts to the middle and leaves equal-length conductors on each side.

Comment: It's easy to find parts on Digi-Key, finding ones *in stock* is something else :P  In any case, I'd post on the duplicate of this question if it would add there (linked by Kellen in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

See [these tips on OpenCircuits.](http://www.opencircuits.com/Solderless_protoboard#More%20Tips)

> In one salvage job I found some
> "double ended" headers, long pins on
> both ends. These can be very handy
> because once plugged in they can be
> used to let you plug in female
> connectors ( like those on hard drive
> cables ( but just one of the two sides
> ) to the board. See pictures below.
> Hard part to find. But wait, you can
> solder two regular headers back to
> back.

> Expanding on the "double ended" header
> above. Right angle headers are long
> enough to bend the pins so they are
> long on both sides. Take a dual row
> one and bend the pins to fit across
> the gap at the center of the proto
> board. Then you can plug in a dual
> plug like those on hard drive cables

Answer (score 0):

If you can still find wire wrap headers, they are a great material to cut up for things like this.

But for insertion in a breadboard you probably don't want "full size" (.025" square iirc) pins but smaller diameter ones to avoid damaging the breadboard (unless you are willing to dedicate those rows to this header)

If it's only three leads and you have the female socket on the cable, I might personally be tempted to insert three pieces of bare wire in the socket and plug the other ends into the breadboard, then tack the socket down with a wire strap, or hot glue or something.   You could also make up a three wire twisted or braided cable of 22 or 24 gauge solid, insert one end in the socket and cover the joint with heat shrink and run the other end into the breadboard.

Answer (score -1):

You really want them to come with equal lengths (like me)

See these Sullins ones [on digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PEC36SABN/S1022E-36-ND/859189).

- The [datasheet](http://www.sullinscorp.com/catalogs/77_PAGE108-109_.100_MALE_HDR.pdf) gives the codes for the head length == tail length.